# break even time

Tags: profits

How can we know **a company's break even time?**

I know how to calculate the break even point. 
I am also assuming that the lower your break even point, the less time it may take you to reach it.

However, the break even point analysis only tells us **the number of goods a company has to sell in order to break even**, and not the time it takes to sell that quantity. Let us say our Break even Point is 50 000 goods. How can we estimate how much time it will take for our company to produce and sell that amount, i.e to break even? What are the values we need to know?

Thank you very much

Comment: Seems like you are asking how to estimate the time $t(x)$ it takes to produce $x$ units of a good. The part about breaking even is superfluous.

Comment: More like the time it takes for $x$ units of a good to be sold?

Comment: And how can we estimate that time?